# Cannot autowire service "App\Service\MatchCarAdService": argument "$templating" of method

Tags: php, symfony

Hi I'm creating a service. This is the code,

```
namespace App\Service;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use App\Entity\CarAd;

class MatchCarAdService {

    protected $mailer;
    protected $templating;


    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, \Swift_Mailer $mailer, $templating) {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->templating = $templating;
    }

    public function sendMail() {
        $message = (new \Swift_Message('Hello Email'))
                ->setFrom('vimuths@yahoo.com')
                ->setTo('vimuths@yahoo.com')
                ->setBody(
                $this->templating->render(
                        // templates/emails/matching-cars.html.html.twig
                        'emails/matching-cars.html.html.twig', []
                ), 'text/html'
        );

    $this->mailer->send($message);
```

This is services.yml

```
MatchCarAdService:
            class: App\Service\MatchCarAdService
            arguments: ['@mailer','@templating']
```

But I'm getting this error,

> Cannot resolve argument $matchService of
>   "App\Controller\Api\SearchController()": Cannot autowire service
>   "App\Service\MatchCarAdService": argument "$templating" of method
>   "__construct()" has no type-hint, you should configure its value
>   explicitly.

Comment: Side notice: don't inject the container - keep on injecting the real dependencies!

Comment: thanks for the advice :) will do in future. BTW my team lead told the same ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now your constructor has 3 parameters but in arguments you are putting 2 only.

So there are two possible solutions:

**Configure in your yaml**

```
MatchCarAdService:
            class: App\Service\MatchCarAdService
            arguments: ['@container', '@mailer','@templating']
```

**Use auto wiring with type hint**
There it depends on your Symfony version, but change constructor to

```
    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, \Swift_Mailer $mailer, Symfony\Component\Templating\EngineInterface; $teplating) {
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->templating = $templating;
    }
```

And you may have to `composer require symfony/templating` in order to get the `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface` service.

Also the following configuration has to be added under `framework`:

```
templating:
        enabled: true
        engines: ['twig']
```

Comment: Added a require code as needed. Thanks so so much for your fix. +1

Comment: I might add that you are actually defining two services here.  One in you service definition and one by autowire.  This is happening because your service id is MatchCarAdService instead of the full class name: App\Service\MatchCarAdService  It is also interesting to note that once you type-hint the template parameter, you no longer need the service definition at all.  Experiment a bit with "bin/console debug:container MatchCarAd" to see what is going on.  It will help you in the future.

Answer (score 2):

## Symfony 3.3+ Answer

Answer by @M. Kebza solves your situation. But you can make this even simpler and bug-proof. Just use Symfony 3.3+ features.

#### A. Use Autowiring

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true

    App\Service\MatchCarAdService: ~
    App\Service\CleaningService: ~
    App\Service\RentingService: ~
```

#### B. Use Autowiring + Autodiscovery - Even better!

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true

    App\:
        resource: ../src
```

This load all services in `App\` namespace from `../src` directory by PSR-4 convention.

You can see more examples in [How to refactor to new Dependency Injection features in Symfony 3.3](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/05/07/how-to-refactor-to-new-dependency-injection-features-in-symfony-3-3/) post.